# How to iterate over ResultProxy many times?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I execute the following query:

```
results = db.engine.execute(sql_query)
```

where it returns rows as expected:

```
>>> for record in results:
...     print(record['path'])
... 
Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars
Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies
Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts
```

When I try to iterate over it a second or third time the object is empty:

```
>>> for record in results:
...     print(record['path'])
...
>>>
```

**How can I save and reuse the ResultProxy to iterate over it many times?**

Comment: Don't you want just to get a `list` of results and then iterate over it?

Comment: I guess it does work:  results = list(results), results[0]['path'] returns the path, I'm kinda surprised it has knowledge of the column references

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have an *iterator* object being returned, so once it's exhausted after iterating over it, you can't go over it again. Assuming your results are not extremely large, you can do:

```
results = db.engine.execute(sql_query) 
results = list(results)
```

That turns the iterator object into a list and you can iterate over it as many times as you would.